# How can I add an accelerator to open a GEdit menu

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, gedit

I have the following code to add a menu 'Shoebot', I would like to be able to open the menu using Alt-B, I can't find any info on how though

```
    ui_str = """
<ui>
  <menubar name="MenuBar">
    <menu name="ShoebotMenu" action="Shoebot">
      <placeholder name="ShoebotOps_1">
        <menuitem name="Run in Shoebot" action="ShoebotRun"/>
        <separator/>
        <menuitem name="Enable Socket Server" action="ShoebotSocket"/>
        <menuitem name="Show Variables Window" action="ShoebotVarWindow"/>
        <menuitem name="Go Fullscreen" action="ShoebotFullscreen"/>
      </placeholder>
    </menu>
  </menubar>
</ui>
"""

self.action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup("ShoebotPluginActions")
self.action_group.add_actions([
    ("Shoebot", None, _("Shoebot"), None, _("Shoebot"), None),
    ("ShoebotRun", None, _("Run in Shoebot"), '<control>R', _("Run in Shoebot"), self.on_run_activate),
    ])
self.action_group.add_toggle_actions([
    ("ShoebotSocket", None, _("Enable Socket Server"), '<control><alt>S', _("Enable Socket Server"), self.toggle_socket_server, False),
    ("ShoebotVarWindow", None, _("Show Variables Window"), '<control><alt>V', _("Show Variables Window"), self.toggle_var_window, False),
    ("ShoebotFullscreen", None, _("Go Fullscreen"), '<control><alt>F', _("Go Fullscreen"), self.toggle_fullscreen, False),
    ])
manager.insert_action_group(self.action_group)
self.ui_id = manager.add_ui_from_string(ui_str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, it was fairly straightforward, adding _b in the add_actions:

```
self.action_group.add_actions([
("Shoebot", None, _("Shoe_bot"), None, _("Shoebot"), None),
("ShoebotRun", None, _("Run in Shoebot"), '<control>R', _("Run in Shoebot"), self.on_run_activate),
])
```

self.action_group.add_toggle_actions([
    ("ShoebotSocket", None, _("Enable Socket Server"), 'S', _("Enable Socket Server"), self.toggle_socket_server, False),
    ("ShoebotVarWindow", None, _("Show Variables Window"), 'V', _("Show Variables Window"), self.toggle_var_window, False),
    ("ShoebotFullscreen", None, _("Go Fullscreen"), 'F', _("Go Fullscreen"), self.toggle_fullscreen, False),
    ])